# Получение описания ПК программно

Tags: c#

В свойствах "Компьютера", в блоке "Имя компьютера, имя домена и параметры рабочей группы".
Имя компьютера и параметры раб.группы можно получить программно, используя методы классы Environments.
А как программно получить описание компьютера(на скриншоте - между "Полное имя" и "Рабочая группа")?

[image: Имя компьютера, имя домена и параметры рабочей группы]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В классе `System.Environments` нет методов, возвращающих описание компьютера. Однако есть другие возможности получить описание компьютера. Рассмотрим более детально два варианта решения поставленной задачи.

### Решение #1

Можно получить описание компьютера из реестра. Есть путь реестра, где лежит описание компьютера:

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\srvcomment

Используя метод [Registry.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) необходимо сделать следующее:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;  

string key = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters";
string computerDescription = (string)Registry.GetValue(key, "srvcomment", null);
```

### Решение #2

Можно использовать [ManagementObjectSearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx). Пример кода:

```
public static void RetrieveComputerProps()
{
  //initialize the select query with command text
  SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(@"Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");

  //initialize the searcher with the query it is supposed to execute
  using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
  {
    //execute the query
    foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
    {
        //print system info
        process.Get();
        Console.WriteLine("/*********Computer System Information ***************/");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "Caption :", process["Caption"]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "Description:", process["Description"]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "Manufacturer:", process["Manufacturer"]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "Model:", process["Model"]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}","TotalPhysicalMemory:",process["TotalPhysicalMemory"]);
    }
  }
}
```

Полученный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Немного доработал решение от Дениса, добавив вывод всех свойств из Win32_ComputerSystem (указанных 5 свойств может быть недостаточно)

```
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
    {
        mo.Get();
        foreach (PropertyData prop in mo.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Полно других полезных Win32_ классов, их можно запросить следующим образом:

```
List<string> classes = new List<string>();
ManagementObjectSearcher wmi = 
   new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM meta_class WHERE __CLASS LIKE 'Win32_%'");
foreach (ManagementObject obj in wmi.Get())
{
    var cls = obj["__CLASS"].ToString();
    //не больше 1 подчеркивания в названии
    if (cls.Count(c => c == '_') < 2)
        classes.Add(cls);
}

foreach (string cls in classes)
    Console.WriteLine(cls);
Console.WriteLine("*** Всего основных Win32_ классов: " + classes.Count);
```